# How to find many item in one parameter Spring data jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to do a data search on spring data jpa, with only one parameter but can search several items. I have list data, like this.

```
{
    "id": 105,
    "roomId": 43,
    "floor": "1",
    "roomNumber": "001",
    "description": "Normal",
    "status": "Vacant Clean"
},
{
    "id": 11,
    "bedTypeName": "King size"
},
{
    "id": 39,
    "categoryName": "President Suite"
}
```

I want to search by roomNumber,bedTypeName, and categoryName. But, in one parameter. For example i have `@Param("roomNumber")` for search 3 item. Example `"roomNumber":"001"`then show filter by rooomNumber. Example `"roomNumber":"king size"` then show filter by bedType. Example `"roomNumber":"president suite"` then show filter by categoryName. In one parameter can search many item.

Here is my repository

```
@Query("select a,b.bedType,b.roomCategory from RoomDetail a left outer join RoomMaster b on a.roomId = b.id where lower(a.roomNumber) interests like %:roomNumber% OR interests LIKE %:bedTypeName% OR interests LIKE %:categoryName%")
Page<RoomDetail> findByRoomNumberBedTypeRoomCategor(
        @Param("roomNumber") String roomNumber, Pageable paging);
```

Comment: did you look over my answer? Just curious,... If you find helpful/unnecessary/need-to-update/unrelated-answer, please let me know.

Comment: @ShekharRai thanks sir.. i have found the answer myself. And it works :)

Comment: that's great. you can post your own answer as well and mark your answer as accepted one so that later on that would be helpful for some other people in the future

Comment: @ShekharRai Ok.. you can look my answer now.. I have added in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer like this.. i have found the answer myself. And it works :)

```
     @Query("select a,b.bedType,b.roomCategory from RoomDetail a left outer join RoomMaster b on a.roomId = b.id where lower(a.roomNumber) like %:filter% "
        + "or lower(b.bedType.bedTypeName) like %:filter% "
        + "or lower(b.roomCategory.categoryName) like %:filter%")
  Page<RoomDetail> findByBedTypeOrRoomCategoryOrRoomNumber(@Param("filter") String Filter, Pageable paging);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using custom query methods via JpaRepository interface. With custom query methods you can generate your repos like :

```
public interface RoomDetailRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<RoomDetail, Integer> { 
    Page<RoomDetail> findByRoomNumberOrBedTypeOrRoomCategoryContains(String search, Pageable pageable);}
```

You can include sorting keywords in your method names as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) instead of writing a painful query and vague JpaRepository method.

**[JpaSpecificationExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html)**

At first extend JpaSpecificationExecutor in your repository interface,

```
interface RoomRepository extends JpaRepository<RoomDetail, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<RoomDetail> {
    // your other queries
}
```

**Specification**

You need to create Specification to lookup the value on needed columns,

```
public static Specification<RoomDetail> search(String value) {
    String search = "%" + value + "%";
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder.or(
            builder.like(root.get("roomNumber"), search),
            builder.like(root.get("bedTypeName"), search),
            builder.like(root.get("categoryName"), search)
    );
}
```

**Search :)**

Now you can use it where you want to search from.

```
Page<RoomDetail> filteredRooms = roomDetailRepository.findAll(search(value), paging);
```

**FYI**

As it looks at every value on `roomNumber, bedTypeName, categoryName` columns, there might be some cases on which multiple rooms will be filtered if **the same value** exists in different rooms columns unless you have *unique values*.

```
| id  | roomid | floor | roomNumber | bedTypeName |  categoryName   |   description    |    status    |
|-----|--------|-------|------------|-------------|-----------------|------------------|--------------|
| 105 |     43 |     1 |        001 | Single      | Junior Suite    | Normal Size      | Vacant Clean |
| 106 |     16 |     1 |        002 | Double      | Business Suite  | Couple Suitable  | Booked       |
| 121 |     23 |     2 |        020 | King Size   | President Suite | Very comfortable | Vacant Clean |
```

In the above case if you give `Size` as a filter value you will get two rooms because id with 105 has *Normal Size* value on *categoryName* column and id with 121 has *King Size* on your *bedTypeName* column.

Moreover: to match the exact value, you may need to update search specification using `builder.equals` instead of `builder.like` but make sure that **% should not** be appended before and after the `value`.

**Explore**

1. [Spring official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)
2. [spring-data-criteria-queries](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries)
3. [spring-data-jpa-specification](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification)